# AWS MSK connection issue using IAM Role authentication from Logstash

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, aws-msk, aws-msk-connect

my logstash configuration is

i am using [aws-msk-auth](https://github.com/aws/aws-msk-iam-auth) plugin

```
kafka {
          codec => "json"
          topic_id => "my_topic"
          bootstrap_servers => "my_iamBroder:9098"
          security_protocol => "SASL_SSL"
          sasl_mechanism => "AWS_MSK_IAM"
          sasl_jaas_config => "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required awsRoleArn='my_role_arn' sasl.client.callback.handler.class='software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler';"
        }
```

error message showing as below

```
[2022-07-26T07:29:29,927][ERROR][org.apache.kafka.common.utils.KafkaThread] Uncaught exception in thread 'kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1':
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/errors/IllegalSaslStateException
    at software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.internals.IAMSaslClient$IAMSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient(IAMSaslClient.java:216) ~[aws-msk-iam-auth-1.1.4.jar:?]
    at javax.security.sasl.Sasl.createSaslClient(Sasl.java:433) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.lambda$createSaslClient$0(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:217) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.createSaslClient(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:213) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.<init>(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:204) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.buildClientAuthenticator(SaslChannelBuilder.java:274) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.lambda$buildChannel$1(SaslChannelBuilder.java:216) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.<init>(KafkaChannel.java:142) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.buildChannel(SaslChannelBuilder.java:224) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.buildAndAttachKafkaChannel(Selector.java:338) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.registerChannel(Selector.java:329) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:?]
```

Comment: how did you solve this issues?

Comment: switched to SCRAM_SSL for now